# UDF on spark Dataframe while executing select API in JAVA

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark. I am trying to execute select statement on spark data frame with UDF, but I could not. I am writing code in java not in scala.

My code is :

```java
DataFrame kafkaDF = sqlCtx.read().json("D:/Normalized/output_raw7.json");
kafkaDF .select("uid", "udftoconvert2long(bytesin)");
```

In the above code how to write my own udf i.e. udftoconvert2long

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
object UDFs {
    def myUdf(bytesIn:String) : Long = ... 


}
```

and then `sqlCtx.udf.register("udftoconvert2long",(bytesIn : String)=> UDFs.myUdf(bytesIn))`

Comment: Hi Amon, Thanks for the response. But I am looking for a UDF to operate with DataFrame not with sqlCtx. I am looking for something like....................kafkaDF.select("uid", "udftoconvert2long(bytesin)");

Comment: form the SPARK documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) :  "
Functions that are used to register UDFs, either for use in the DataFrame DSL or SQL, have been moved into the udf object in SQLContext."

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link will be helpful for you 
https://pythagoreanscript.wordpress.com/2015/05/30/spark-sql-udf-user-defined-functions/

Comment: While this link may answer the question it is not a satisfactory response.  Please provide some explanation here of how to solve the problem, perhaps including some code.

Comment: I know how to do in scala never executed same code in java will test and then update here , for help i just updated the link , will be updating soon. thanks for update